# How to find a value that XORs to another value?

Tags: javascript, math, xor

I'm trying to have 3 keys that XOR to the master key value.

```
A XOR B XOR C = MASTER KEY
```

If A, B and the MASTER KEY can be generated as a randomByte(LENGTH=32), how can I find the C value? (in javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since XOR is its own inverse (that is `A XOR A = 0` for all bit patterns, `A`), you can find `C` by the following:

```
C = A ^ B ^ MASTER_KEY;
```

Where `^` is the JavaScript XOR operator, and `A`, `B`, and `MASTER_KEY` are the values you defined above.

Answer (score 2):

Since XOR is the inverse operation of XOR and XOR is commutative, you can just apply basic arithmetics:

```
A XOR B XOR C = M    | XOR C
A XOR B = M XOR C    | XOR M
A XOR B XOR M = C
```

And in javascript syntax:

```
var C = A ^ B ^ MASTER_KEY;
```